# Java FX, function not working properly

Tags: java, javafx

I have to write a program that reads and displays all the words from a text file in ascending alphabetical order. The text file is passed as a command-line argument.The program must also have a input box, submit button, and the result displays below them in the same window.

I have edited the program and cleaned it up. Deleted the filename method and called the button method to make it simpler and try to get the submit button to work. However, it seems nothing has changed. Everything works up unto the point that I press the submit button and then nothing happens.

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class AlphabeticalOrder extends Application {

   TextField fileName = new TextField();
   Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
   TextArea outputArea = new TextArea();

   public void button() {
       submitButton.setOnAction(e -> {
           if(fileName.getText().length() > 0) {
               submitButtonClick();
           }
       });
   }

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
       try {
           BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

           Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

           primaryStage.show();

           // Set the stage title
           primaryStage.setTitle("AlphabeticalOrder");

           // Place the scene in the stage
           primaryStage.setScene(scene);

           // Display the stage
           primaryStage.show();

           // Hold a button in an HBox
           HBox inputBox = new HBox();
           inputBox.setSpacing(10);
           inputBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
           inputBox.getChildren().addAll(new Text("Filename:"));
           inputBox.getChildren().addAll(fileName);
           inputBox.getChildren().addAll(submitButton);
           root.setTop(inputBox);

           //This creates a text box to display the results
           //from reading the file in a pane
           outputArea.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black");
           outputArea.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey");
           root.setCenter(outputArea);
       } catch(Exception e) {
           button();
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }


   public void submitButtonClick() {
       if(fileName.getText().length() > 0) {
          File sourceFile = new File(fileName.getText());
         if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
             System.out.println("Source file " + fileName.getText()
                  + " does not exist");
          }
       }

       fileName.setText("Test 1");
   }

   class SortFile
   {
       //sorting function
   void sortArray(String array[]) {
       //Loop for no.of passes
   for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++)

       //Repeat no.of comparisons
       for(int j=0;j<array.length-i-1;j++)

           //Comparing adjacent elements
           if(array[j].compareTo(array[j+1])>0)
   {
               //Swap using temp variable
               String temp=array[j];
               array[j]=array[j+1];
               array[j+1]=temp;
              }
   }
   public void reader(String args[])
   {
       //Creating File object
       File freader;

       //Scanner for reading
       Scanner filescanner;

       //Array list for dynamic elements adding
   ArrayList <String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

   //If file name is no.of passed as argument is 1
   if(args.length==1)
   {
   try
   {
       //Create file object
       freader = new File(args[0]);

       //Reading from file
       filescanner = new Scanner(freader);

       //Reading until end of file
   while(filescanner.hasNext())
   {
       //Reading each word and to Array List
       array.add(filescanner.next());
   }
   }
   //If file IOException is thrown
      catch(IOException ie)
   {
   System.out.println(ie);
   }String[] newArray = new String[array.size()];

   //Convert Array list to ArraynewArray=array.toArray(newArray);

   System.out.println("List of strings from file Before Sorting : \n");

   //Print before sorting words
   for(int i=0;i<newArray.length;i++)
   System.out.print(newArray[i]+" ");

   //Call sorting method
   sortArray(newArray);
   System.out.println("\nList of strings from file After Sorting : \n");

   //Print after sorting words
   for(int i=0;i<newArray.length;i++)
   System.out.print(newArray[i]+" ");

   System.out.print("\n");
   }
   else
       //If file name is not passed as argument then show usage syntax
       System.out.println("Usage syntax: SoftFile <Words.rtf>");}
   }
   }
```

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You never hook up the handler to your submit button - the `button` function which does this is only called once, by `filename`, which in turn never gets called.

Edit: I suggest you take the time to read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm).

Comment: Where would I call the fileName method

Comment: You are still only calling it in the `catch` block. I'm not sure what you are expecting to happen.